# NetBeans не выдает желаемое

Tags: java, netbeans

Учусь java. Скачал NetBeans. Попробовал написать первую программу, вот что выдал:[image: "Screen NetBeans"] Что поправить, чтоб выводилась надпись из System.out.print(a)?

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно помню, в выпадающем списке возле кнопок "Undo"/"Redo" должен быть выбран конфиг для запуска, где указывается "главный" класс и, соответственно, стартовый метод. У вас там пусто. Откройте этот список, выберите имеющийся там конфиг. Если нет - создайте новый, указав главным классом ваш.

Ну и совет, которого вы не просили. Не мучайте себя нетБинсом. Лагучая, неповоротливая, да и просто уродливая штука. Переезжайте на Intelij IDEA или хотя бы на Eclipse

Comment: Спасибо большое!!!